# Titan performance increases when removing edges

Tags: performance, titan

Following is my test program for testing the performance when removing edges in Titan:

```
        Vertex v1 = g.addVertex( null );

        int i = 0;
        long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while ( true ) {
            Vertex v2 = g.addVertex( null );

            Iterable iterable = v1.getEdges( Direction.IN, "last-data" );
            for( Edge e : iterable ) {
                e.remove();
            }

            v2.addEdge( "last-data", v1 );

            g.commit();

            if ( i % 100 == 0 ) {
                long duration = ( System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime );
                System.out.println( "count:" + String.format( "%7s", i ) + ", duration:" + String.format( "%7s", duration ) + "ms");
                lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } // end if
            i++;
        } // end while
```

Over time, the time taken to remove the edge gets longer and longer, even though the number of edges remains 1 all the time.

Is this a bug?
Shouldn't the time taken to remove the edge remains constant since number of edges is always 1?
What causing this behaviour?
Anyway workaround?

Comment: which backend are you using? cassandra?

Comment: Yes i am using cassandra 2.0.4 as backend storage. is cassandra causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you remove an edge it may be gone from the graph's perspective, but it is actually tombstoned for deletion on a future compaction.

Your code is adding edges to one existing vertex, i.e. `v1`, (and a newly created vertex on each loop) and removing it by deleting the edge from `v1`.  That means that as the number of deleted edges grows prior to compaction, you are forced to read the tombstone data to get to the last added edge.

Aside from performing a compaction, one alternative is to delete the edge from the opposite direction (i.e. from `v2`) or to delete the edge by its ID.  These methods have gotten me past these problems.  Given your code specifically, assuming that was a real-world problem, where  you were rapidly adding/removing edges from a supernode, then some form of vertex-centric query might help...like:

```
v1.query().limit(1).edges()
```

That *might* fix your "test code" though, you would have to just try and see.  This approach worked for me (you can just paste in to the Titan Gremlin REPL):

```
g = TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-cassandra.properties')

v1 = g.addVertex(null)

bytes = new byte[ 65536 ]
Arrays.fill( bytes, (byte) 0 )

i = 0;
lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
toRemove = null
while ( true ) {
  def v2 = g.addVertex( null );
  v2.setProperty('b',bytes)

  if (toRemove != null) toRemove.remove()

  toRemove = v2.addEdge( "last-data", v1 );

  g.commit();

  if ( i % 100 == 0 ) {
      def duration = ( System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime );
      println "count:" + String.format( "%7s", i ) + ", duration:" + String.format( "%7s", duration ) + "ms"
      lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  } // end if
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Interesting....i accidentally left your programming running by accident.  got to about 3M edges with not much degredation.  sorta strange.  anyway, my answer still stands as I have seen this behavior before.

Comment: 3M edges? Do you mean 3M loops? coz i remove the edges every loop so there should be 1 edge (as you said from graph's perspective) at all times. I am running on a i7 desktop, I see the degradation effect almost immediately (less than 10000 loops)

Comment: I tried `v1.query().limit(1).edges();`, does not help.  Isn't `v1.getEdges( Direction.IN, "last-data" );` the same as `v1.query().direction( Direction.IN ).labels( "last-data" ).edges();` which is a vertex query?

Comment: I did mean 3M loops, but i had a mis-configuration so my previous answer was bad. I was able to reproduce your problem with help from @daniel-kuppitz . I started to see performance degradation around 10000 loops as you mentioned.  I've updated my answer and included a groovy script that ended up working for me. Even with that model I'm seeing spikes however I think that's just due to cassandra having to flush the commit logs.  You could likely do better if you didn't commit on every single cycle of the loop.

Comment: I've posted my results [here](https://github.com/yammelvin/TitanTestsRepository/tree/master/TitanTestProgram/log). I think my test program is very similar to the program described [here](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Vertex-Centric-Indices) @ the titan wiki, but I cannot reached a stable performance eventhough it is always doing the same thing every loop.

Comment: Have you specifically tried to execute the code i posted in the REPL?  It does not show the same steep performance as you show in that repo.  @daniel-kuppitz has tried that code and sees the same steady loop times that I do.  It would be nice for us to know if that exact same groovy code works in your environment or not. Thanks.

Comment: OK. I ran the code in the Titan Grelim REPL. The climb is more obvious when I println every 1000 loops instead. The results are [here](https://github.com/yammelvin/TitanTestsRepository/blob/master/TitanTestProgram/log/titan-gremlin.cassandra.log). Yes the performance is climbing much slower compared to using ```.getEdges()``` and then removing the edge, but it is still climbing. It will most probably be a problem if the program is to run 24/7/365.

Comment: And also, does that mean that there is an issue with v.getEdges()? Because when I include the v.getEdges() in the loop, the climb is so much steeper.

Comment: I don't think there's any other explanation or workaround beyond what I've provided.  You might want to spend some time reading about tombstones and compaction in Cassandra.  You mention that a running program doing this 24/7/365...I'd hope that you were running necessary repairs and maintenance on cassandra during that time which would help mitigate this issue, but assuming you weren't, I'd wonder what the use case was that required a program to do this and if there was a different model for the graph that would help alleviate the problem.  That's probably a different question though. :)

Comment: Is there a way for titan to force a compaction in Cassandra?

Comment: No...it is not a Titan function.  It is a function of Cassandra.

Comment: Today I started this script again and let it run for several hours. Short summary: no degradation at all. Times above 1 second were very rare during the whole test.

Comment: I know compaction is in Cassandra, but I'm wondering if there is a way for titan to force Cassandra to do a compaction. This is because if I am using Titan, it would be very unlikely for me to work Cassandra directly, else I would lose the abstraction.

Comment: OK thanks guys. My intention was to store live streaming videos from multiple cctv cameras continuously in a graph database 24/7 and probably 365 if storage capacity allows, plus the ability to provide high availability and horizontal scalability. Titan / Cassandra combination seemed like a perfect choice until I encounter this issue. Looks like I probably have to think of some other way. Thanks again.

Comment: Compaction is an administrative function.  Titan does not remove the need to understand the underlying data store (i.e. cassandra) and how to maintain it.  You will need to administer it (e.g. add nodes, re-balance the cluster, backups, etc.)

Comment: I would not store video (or any large binary files) directly in the graph.  Store them elsewhere (e.g. S3, maybe a separate cassandra cluster, etc.) then reference their locations in the graph with any required meta data.

Comment: Oh ok. I thought compaction was a period function done automatically by Cassandra. My bad.

Comment: Perhaps you were thinking of a "minor" compaction.  Those occur periodically.

Answer (score 0):

The degradation can be speed up doing a `setProperty` on every `v2` created, as follows:

```
    byte[] bytes = new byte[ 65536 ];
    Arrays.fill( bytes, (byte) 0 );

    Vertex v1 = g.addVertex( null );
    Edge pE = null;

    int i = 0;
    long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while ( true ) {
        Vertex v2 = g.addVertex( null );
        v2.setProperty( "chunk", bytes );

        if ( pE != null ) {
            pE.remove();
        }

        pE = v2.addEdge( "last-data", v1 );

        g.commit();

        if ( i % 1000 == 0 ) {
            long duration = ( System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime );
            System.out.println( "count:" + String.format( "%7s", i ) + ", duration:" + String.format( "%7s", duration ) + "ms" );
            lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } // end if
        i++;
    } // end while
```

and even if I keep the previous edge `pE`, the performance will still climb, but at a slower rate ( less than 50000 loops).

Comment: Hey Melvin, please share the output of your test, so that everybody knows which numbers we are talking about. Here's mine for 5000 loops: http://dpaste.com/1776449/

Comment: Hi Daniel and Stephen. I've tried titan with berkeleyje, embedded cassandra and remote cassandra. The results are [here](https://github.com/yammelvin/TitanTestsRepository/tree/master/TitanTestProgram/log), together with my test program. It seems that the performance is climbing for both embedded and remote cassandra, but not for berkeleyje.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely that the performance degradation is due to the piling up of tombstones that mark the deletion of previously added edges. Those are only cleared out on the next compaction. This is why you see a performance hit on Cassandra and less so on BerkeleyJe (which deals with deletes differently).

There are some tuning options to get better performance for such use cases, but fundamentally, this behavior will not go away.
We are working on supporting time-to-live markers on edges that would allow you to specify an expiration time for edges which would be a more scalable way to deal with deletions in such a context if it applies.

Comment: If this is the case, then after the compaction, shouldn't the performance go back to normal, but so far I have observed that the performance keeps on dropping. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: OK I just understand from stephen that compaction is an administrative function. I thought it was a periodic runtime function.